# How to capture UIEvents of UIButton in custom framework?

Tags: ios, frameworks, uibutton, swift2

I create my own framework and in that I need to provide a button and clicking on button I will do something predefined in framework. 
Here is my code.

```
public class WebButton: NSObject {
    public func enableWebButton(enable:Bool)
    {
        if(enable)
        {
            let appWindow =  UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
            let webBtn = UIButton(frame:CGRectMake((appWindow?.frame.size.width)! - 70,(appWindow?.frame.size.height)! - 70,50,50))
            let frameworkBundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.classForCoder)
            let img = UIImage(named: "btn_icon.png", inBundle: frameworkBundle, compatibleWithTraitCollection: nil)
            webBtn.setImage(img, forState: .Normal)
            webBtn.layer.cornerRadius = webBtn.frame.size.width / 2;
            webBtn.layer.masksToBounds = true
            webBtn.addTarget(self, action: "webButtonClick", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
            appWindow?.addSubview(webBtn)
            print("btn created")
        }
    }

    func webButtonClick()
    {
        print("btn Clicked")
    }
}
```

In this code, I am getting button on my sample project, but clicking on button, nothing happens.

> "btn created"

log is going to print, but

> "btn Clicked"

is never going to print.
Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code for creating your button and your `webButtonClick` function:

```
public func enableWebButton(enable:Bool)
{
    if(enable)
    {
        let appWindow =  UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
        let webBtn = UIButton(frame:CGRectMake((appWindow?.frame.size.width)! - 70,(appWindow?.frame.size.height)! - 70,50,50))
        let frameworkBundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.classForCoder)
        let img = UIImage(named: "btn_icon.png", inBundle: frameworkBundle, compatibleWithTraitCollection: nil)
        webBtn.setImage(img, forState: .Normal)
        webBtn.layer.cornerRadius = webBtn.frame.size.width / 2;
        webBtn.layer.masksToBounds = true
        webBtn.addTarget(self, action: "webButtonClick:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        appWindow?.addSubview(webBtn)
        print("btn created")
    }
}


func webButtonClick(sender:UIButton!)
{
    print("btn Clicked")
}
```

Comment: Already tried that but no success, also added `@IBAction` before `func` but no success

Comment: the button is being displayed on the screen?

Comment: Yes, button is displaying with my image